# How to add multiple SQL rows to an PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have `$view_data['auth_info']` which is populated with a query row, that works fine. But i need to add an additional row to this array. How is this possible? All the variables are unique, so theres no change i will have to identical definitions.

I tried following:

```
$view_data['auth_info'] = $myFirstSQLRow
array_push($view_data['auth_info'],$mySecondSQLRow);
```

But it failed:

```
Message: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array
```

But isnt the first var an `array` or have i misunderstood something?

Comment: `$view_data['auth_info'] = array($myFirstSQLRow, $mySecondSQLRow)`?

Comment: I want to merge the two variables into one spot. If you understand.

Comment: Very hard to understand what you mean by 'merge'. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Aust, tried to give an example on this merging, which is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). Use it like this:

```
$view_data['auth_info'] = $myFirstSQLRow;
$view_data['auth_info'] = array_merge($view_data['auth_info'], $mySecondSQLRow);
```

As it says in the documentation, you may need to type-cast (by putting `(array)` in front of your variables.)

Comment: I tried this, also by typecasting both vars to (array), but when i try to print the variables `$view_data['auth_info']->name` i get `Message: Undefined offset: 1` and `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @JavaCake - Try this instead: `$view_data['auth_info']['name']`

Comment: Works like a charm. But isnt there a workaround so i still can use the objects rather than typecasting to array?

Comment: @JavaCake - I dunno. Sorry, I've never had to do that. But out of curiosity, why do you need to do that?

Comment: Im querying data from two tables and returning them as rows. I wanted to merge the two rows somehow.

Comment: @JavaCake - No I mean, what can you do with objects that you can't do with arrays in this case? If you have no reasons, then I would suggest doing it like this. :)

Comment: Nothing except the code looks better since im using objects everywhere. I will go with this solution, but eventually i must join my tables to get a neater result. :o) Thanks for the effort!